# Is it possible to pull out the unit test runner pane?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have 2 monitors, and in my left monitor I have intelliJ, and in my right monitor I want to drag out the unit-test runner panel onto another monitor or to the side.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just convert the panel to a window, using the floating mode setting. Like here: [image]